# Blank PDF with Express Request

Tags: node.js, express, node-request

I am getting a blank pdf when viewing in the browser and the request works because every time i search for a different pdf (localhost:3001/sample.pdf) the page numbers change, i have seen many questions asked about this and I have tried all their advice (base64 stuff, Buffer.from stuff, content-type app/pdf stuff), still haven't got it working.

```
app.get('/:file', function(req, res) {
    request('http://host/path/' + req.params.file, function(error, response, body) {
       res.end(body);
    });    
}).listen(port);
```

pls point me in right direction!

Comment: If you're trying to send a PDF file to the client, `res.end(data)` is not correct.  You need to send something that the browser understands.  That would probably be a specific content-type for the PDF file and then properly encoded PDF data, not raw data.  In this case, you can probably just stream from the `request()` directly to `res` (e.g. just forward the response you're getting to the client directly) since some other server has already formatted it properly  for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't sending a properly defined response that has proper headers, content-type and matching encoded data.  Since the server you are fetching the PDF from has already done that for you, I'd suggest you just `.pipe()` the response directly.

```
app.get('/:file', function(req, res) {
    request('http://host/path/' + req.params.file).pipe(res);    
}).listen(port);
```

Answer (score -1):

Explore the metadata values of the PDF.Specifically **Xref tables** .If Xref tables is corrupted somehow the pdf application will not be able to resolve the objects inside the file and file will open as blank.